# Android Material Design issues updated from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

I updated 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' library to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' from gradle, but now my application ends by returning InflateException.

Full exception here:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.concas.diffapp, PID: 3893
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.concas.diffapp/com.concas.diffapp.activities.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.concas.diffapp.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:82)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:120)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:424)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:396)
        ... 32 more
```

My style:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.Login">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="#2B579A"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I could solve by changing parent style with Theme.MaterialComponents.+++.+++ or implement items in AppTheme section but doing so I alter the graphics and colors and I don't want to edit them again. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

In manifest i set theme as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Login"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge" />
```

In layout i set TextInput as:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="30"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Adding the following properties:

```
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `AppCompat` themes with `MaterialComponents` views. `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` are Material Design Components. They both don't go together.

Comment: you want dark action bar right? Correct me if I am wrong. I am asking from theme point of view. I got it that you want to display that material edittext input

Comment: Try using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar" >` in your `styles.xml`

Comment: I said "I could solve by changing parent style with Theme.MaterialComponents.+++.+++ or implement items in AppTheme section but doing so I alter the graphics and colors and I don't want to edit them again. Any other solution?" I would like the UI to remain unchanged as in version 1.0.0, I am attaching a screenshot https://i.postimg.cc/Dy67DCZ0/Screenshot-20200402-200018-Diffapp.jpg

Comment: Sorry, my bad didn't understand that part properly. I would say maybe migrate your project properly to Androidx first. There is something wrong where its picking up wrong part. `Refractor menu --> Migrate to AndroidX`. This usually solves some weird issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210823/discussion-between-xxconcasxx-and-darpal-dhyani).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in this error message

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

Using Material widgets will require using a theme from the `Theme.MaterialComponents` family starting 1.1.0.

[Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) guide explains what to do:

> #### 4. Change your app theme to inherit from a Material Components theme
>
> Doing an app-wide migration by changing your app theme to inherit from a Material Components theme is the recommended approach. However, be sure to test thoroughly afterwards, as components in existing layouts may change their looks and behavior.
>
> Note: If you **can't** change your theme, you can do one of the following:
>
> - Inherit from one of our Material Components **Bridge** themes. See the **Bridge Themes** section for more details.
> - Continue to inherit from an AppCompat theme and add some new theme attributes to your theme. See the **App Compat Themes** section for more details.
>
> [...]
>
> **Bridge Themes**
>
> If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you
>   can inherit from a Material Components **Bridge** theme.
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
>     <!-- ... -->
> </style>
> ```
>
> Both `Theme.MaterialComponents` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` have
>   `.Bridge` themes:
>
> - `Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge`
> - `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge`
> - `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge`
> - `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`
> - `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge`
>
> Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material
>   Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start
>   using Material Design components without changing your app theme.
>
> **AppCompat Themes**
>
> You can also incrementally test new Material components without changing
>   your app theme. This allows you to keep your existing layouts looking and
>   behaving the same, while introducing new components to your layout one at a
>   time.
>
> However, you must add the following new theme attributes to your existing app
>   theme, or you will encounter `ThemeEnforcement` errors:
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
>
>   <!-- Original AppCompat attributes. -->
>   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_app_primary_color</item>
>   <item name="colorSecondary">@color/my_app_secondary_color</item>
>   <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_app_background_color</item>
>   <item name="colorError">@color/my_app_error_color</item>
>
>   <!-- New MaterialComponents attributes. -->
>   <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/my_app_primary_variant_color</item>
>   <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/my_app_secondary_variant_color</item>
>   <item name="colorSurface">@color/my_app_surface_color</item>
>   <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/my_app_color_on_primary</item>
>   <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/my_app_color_on_secondary</item>
>   <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/my_app_color_on_background</item>
>   <item name="colorOnError">@color/my_app_color_on_error</item>
>   <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/my_app_color_on_surface</item>
>   <item name="scrimBackground">@color/mtrl_scrim_color</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline2</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
>   <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline</item>
>
> </style>
> ```

The guide contains a few [useful links](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming.md) at the end, among others [Theming Guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming.md).